# Preencher um vetor com valores randômicos (Linguagem C)

Tags: c

Em mais um de meus estudos na Linguagem C, eu tive a ideia de tentar preencher um vetor alocado dinamicamente com números randômicos. No entanto, me deparei com o seguinte problema: A função rand foi configurada para randomizar um numero a cada segundo. Como a velocidade de preenchimento é rápida demais, o "for" acaba preenchendo esse vetor em menos de um segundo, e por isso, todos os valores inseridos são exatamente iguais.

Meus conhecimentos na área ainda são bastante limitados, então de momento não pude achar nenhuma solução para isso. O que eu sei, é que poderia tirar o srand do meu código. Porém ele iria gerar os mesmos números toda vez que eu reinicializasse a execução dele.

Alguém teria uma ideia? E se tivesse, poderia explicá-la a mim? Sou iniciante. Então é importante que eu entenda o processo.

Obrigado desde já!

```html
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "time.h"

int main()
{
 int k = NULL, *matriz = NULL;


 printf("Tamanho do vetor: ");
 scanf("%i", &k);

 matriz = (int *)malloc(k * sizeof(int));

 for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
 {
  srand(time(NULL));
  matriz[i] = rand() % k + 1;

  printf("Valor  %i : %i" , i+1,  matriz[i]);
  printf("\n");
 }

 system("pause");
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema esta na seguinte linha:

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

A funcao `time(NULL)` tem uma resolução em segundos, ou seja, se a chamar varias vezes no espaço de um segundo, o valor retornado vai ser sempre o mesmo.

Assim, tem o problema de estar a colocar a semente do `rand` (através do `srand(time(NULL)`) sempre no mesmo valor, o que faz com que os valores gerados sejam sempre iguais. Essencialmente, se o `loop` for rápido tem o equivalente a `srand(1)`.

Da [documentação](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/):

> Two different initializations with the same seed will generate the same succession of results in subsequent calls to rand.

Para resolver o problema, mude o `srand(time(NULL)` para fora do `loop`:

```
srand(time(NULL));
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
    matriz[i] = rand() % k + 1;

    printf("Valor  %i : %i" , i+1,  matriz[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Desta forma, os números gerados vão ser diferentes.

Comment: Uau, obrigado Omni!

Isso realmente resolveu o problema e ficou muito melhor e mais rápido do que as condições que eu havia inserido. Além de tudo, explicou direitinho!

Obrigado!